# System Center Configuration Manager using 'Run Script' feature on devices with AllSigned Execution Policy

Tags: powershell, configuration-management, system-center

We have System Center Configuration Manager version 1902 managing our devices.

I would like to use the nice feature "Run Script", which runs PowerShell scripts on an entire collection of devices, but all our devices have the ExecutionPolicy set to AllSigned (it's a company policy).

It is not working, the script running locally in each device (created by SCCM), isn't digitally signed, so it won't run and returns a blank or a weird "8" value output to SCCM.

On devices with RemoteSigned or Unrestricted ExecutionPolicy (for testing), it works fine, the output return is correct.

Is there a solution to that? Without changing the PowerShell Execution Policy?

Answer (score 0):

ExecutionPolicy isn't really a security setting. It's designed to prevent regular users from inadvertently running an untrusted script. So you may want to run from a cmd script:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File <path to script.ps1>
```

I believe you can also specify `-Command "& C:\Path\To\Script.ps1"`

Comment: Sorry, I know how the ExecutionPolicy works, the problem is that it's the SCCM client agent that runs de script on the hundreds of clients, and as far as I know I can't really change the parameters it uses to invoke the script. It executes like this: 
"Executing command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "& { . 'C:\WINDOWS\CCM\ScriptStore\1E593ECC-42F2-495E-A453-14A6DF93D186_F871C20FBF3EE8130FA52FE3DA983773678B7E04617EAF26EBBCBB3E74AA4622.ps1'  | ConvertTo-Json -Compress } " with options (32, 4)"

Comment: @esserafael: Is the script you are importing signed?